# Adding multiple columns simultaneously with different values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `df` that has some data already. I want to add two new columns. One column should have name `Subject` and the other `Slide`. I want `Subject` to take the value "F1" and Slide to take "1A". Is there a way to create these columns and assign their values at the same time. Of course i could just do this one at a time, but I'm looking for a more general method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::mutate` can create multiple columns at once.

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- head(cars)

mutate(df, Subject = 'F1', Slide = '1A')
#>   speed dist Subject Slide
#> 1     4    2      F1    1A
#> 2     4   10      F1    1A
#> 3     7    4      F1    1A
#> 4     7   22      F1    1A
#> 5     8   16      F1    1A
#> 6     9   10      F1    1A
```

This can also be done in base `R`.

```
df[, c('Subject', 'Slide')] <- list('F1', '1A')
df
#>   speed dist Subject Slide
#> 1     4    2      F1    1A
#> 2     4   10      F1    1A
#> 3     7    4      F1    1A
#> 4     7   22      F1    1A
#> 5     8   16      F1    1A
#> 6     9   10      F1    1A
```